# Stored procedure to delete from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm creating an album and image gallery as a feature for a directory. Basically, a business can create albums, and add images to those albums.

Here are my tables:

- BD_Album (AlbumID, OwnerID, AlbumName)
- BD_Image (ImageID, OwnerID, ImageFile, ImageTitle, ImageDescription, Active)
- BD_AlbumImage (EntryID, AlbumID, ImageID)

I want to create a stored procedure that is executed when the owner deletes an album. My goal for this procedure is to clean up the tables.

```
DELETE FROM BD_Album WHERE AlbumID = @AlbumID --This is the obvious
DELETE FROM BD_Image WHERE ...
DELETE FROM BD_AlbumImage WHERE AlbumID = @AlbumID
```

My confusion comes in where I want to also remove any images from the `BD_Image` table that are associated with that album. (Warning, removing this album will also delete all images from within it. Are you sure?)

The owners are able to create as many albums as they'd like. They can also assign an image to multiple albums via a listbox in the form.

Probably a bit elementary, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DELETE FROM BD_Image 
WHERE ImageID IN 
    (SELECT ImageID FROM BD_AlbumImage WHERE AlbumID = @AlbumID
        AND ImageID  NOT IN 
            (SELECT ImageID FROM BD_AlbumImage WHERE AlbumID <> @AlbumID))
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM BD_Image 
WHERE ImageID IN 
    (SELECT ImageID FROM BD_AlbumImage WHERE AlbumID = @AlbumID)
AND ImageID  NOT IN 
    (SELECT ImageID FROM BD_AlbumImage WHERE AlbumID <> @AlbumID)
```

Comment: I was able to primarily utilize this suggestion, with a few snippets from another. Thank you Nalaka

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the related records from BD_IMAGE in SQL server as follows:

```
DELETE BD_IMAGE
FROM 
    BD_IMAGE i
    JOIN BD_AlbumImage ai
    ON i.ImageID = ai.ImageID
WHERE
    ai.AlbumID = @AlbumID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
delete from BD_Album a,BD_Image i,BD_AlbumImage ai where a.AlbumID = @AlbumID
and ai.AlbumID =a.AlbumID and i.ImageID=ai.ImageID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have setup the tables allows for an image to exist many times in the same album. If you only want 1 entry of image in an album, you don't need an EntryId column in the BD_AlbumImage table, you could simply have AlbumId and ImageId, both those Foreign Keys could constitue the PrimaryKey for that table. The cool thing with that is, you can them put a cascade delete on it to automagically delete the records like so:

```
ALTER TABLE BD_AlbumImage 
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_BD_AlbumImage_BD_Album 
FOREIGN KEY(AlbumID) REFERENCES BD_Album (AlbumID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

With the cascade you don't need to run the last Delete.And then you would say: But hey I'll have Images attached to no album? Yeah you might. If it was me, I wouldn't like that Deleting an album Deletes images in it, I would prefer they remain in an inbox of some sort, but if you wanted to clean out images with no ablums you could then do it like so:

```
DELETE FROM BD_Image 
  LEFT JOIN BD_AlbumImage ON BD_Image.ImageID = BD_AlbumImage.ImageID 
      WHERE BD_AlbumImage.AlbumID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Oxydel. I minimized the table and make the two columns as key.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from BD_Image where ImageID in(select ImageID from BD_AlbumImage where AlbumID=@AlbumID )
delete from BD_AlbumImage  where AlbumID=@AlbumID
delete from BD_Album where AlbumID=@AlbumID
```